# Cumulative distribution function, many random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $F(x) = \frac{1}{2} 1_{[0,1[} + (1-e^{-x})1_{[1,\infty[}$ the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

Let $Z=X 1_{]1,\infty[}$. I have to calculate the cumulative distribution function of $Z$. Then, I have to prove that $Z$ can be written than $Z=BU+(1-B)V$ with $B,U,V$ are random variables independant, $U$ discrete and $V$ continue.

I wrote $F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0  \\ 
1/2 & \text{ if } 0 \leq x < 1  \\ 
1-e^{-x} & \text{ if } x\geq 1  
\end{cases}$

Then $P(Z \leq x) = \begin{cases}
1-e^{-x} & \text{ if } x > 1  \\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$.

But I'm not sure it's the cumulative distribution function of $Z$. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your suggestion for $P(Z\le x)$ when $0\le x\le1$ is wrong. Please review this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $Z:=X\mathbf 1_{X\in\,]0,\infty[}$ means that:$${\begin{split}\{Z\leqslant z<0\}&=\{\}\\ \{0\leqslant Z\leqslant z\leqslant 1\}&=\{X\leqslant 1\} &\qquad = \{Z=0\}\\\{1<Z\leqslant z\} &= \{1<X\leqslant z\}\end{split}}$$

Also recall that CDF is the *Cummulative* Distribution Function.